# Cannot pass PHP variable to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass a php variable to JavaScript that hold the name of the table, data will be written in. However I can not see the value when I console.log it.  The script is activate on click, so it should not be an issue with page load, but I am not very good with JavaScript, so I have no idea what I am doing wrong

```
global $user;
            $user = user_load($user->uid);

            $params = Array (   
                                'company'   =>  $user->field_active_company[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] ,
                            );
$id = $user->name;          
$cu = "db_".$params['company'];
//Here I can see the value fine
echo $cu; 

.
.
.
.
//here I can not.
 var write = '<?php echo json_encode($cu); ?>';
 console.log(write);
var write2 = '<?php echo $cu; ?>';
console.log(write2);
```

### Edit

To clarify:

- I am asking why it does not work (or how to fix it).
- the JavaScript has a function around it and all the needed tags. I am console logging textboxes prior to the JavaScript/PHP part.

Comment: You can not mix php with javascript like that. Is this exacly the code you are using?

Comment: Can you provide a `var_dump($cu)` or `print_r($cu)` ?

Comment: echo: db_0099  print_r: db_0099

Comment: @Hossam Not a dublicate with that. I am not asking how, but why it does not work (it should).

Answer (score 1):

console.log() doesn't print anything if the value is undefined. So maybe php is not rendering the value, or if the value is a string it's lacking double quotes "". You can see what is rendering php in the browser html code. Hope it is just double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know what the issue was. I ended up passing the value through hidden field. This solved my issue, but could not find answer to my question. Daniel was right about the the value not coming through.